# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text Api - Convert json format in plain text w/o variables

Tags: python, json, text, speech-to-text

I used the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API to convert audio files (interviews) to text. This worked quite well, though I struggle with the json output.

Since I only need the transcript result ("Okay, I'm going to read you, the opening question."), I wonder if there is an easy way to delete the variables: "words", "endTime", "startTime" and "word"?

Does anyone know an easy way to do it? Maybe in python?

```json
"results": [ {
    "alternatives": [ {
      "transcript": "Okay, I'm going to read you, the opening question.",
      "words": [ {
        "endTime": "1.800s",
        "startTime": "1.300s",
        "word": "Okay,"
      }, {
        "endTime": "2.800s",
        "startTime": "1.800s",
        "word": "I'm"
      }, {
        "endTime": "3s",
        "startTime": "2.800s",
        "word": "going"
      }, {
        "endTime": "3.100s",
        "startTime": "3s",
        "word": "to"
      }, {
        "endTime": "3.300s",
        "startTime": "3.100s",
        "word": "read"
      }, {
        "endTime": "4.300s",
        "startTime": "3.300s",
        "word": "you"
      }, {
        "endTime": "4.400s",
        "startTime": "4.300s",
        "word": "the"
      }, {
        "endTime": "6s",
        "startTime": "4.400s",
        "word": "opening"
      }, {
        "endTime": "6.200s",
        "startTime": "6s",
        "word": "question."
```

Thanks in advance,
Matt

I did not find any solution, since I have very less experience in data formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I use the speech to text API now, the output looks slightly different:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "transcript": "Okay, I'm going to read you, the opening question.",
                    "words": [
                        {
                            "endTime": "1.800s",
                            "startTime": "1.300s",
                            "word": "Okay,"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "2.800s",
                            "startTime": "1.800s",
                            "word": "I'm"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "3s",
                            "startTime": "2.800s",
                            "word": "going"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "3.100s",
                            "startTime": "3s",
                            "word": "to"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "3.300s",
                            "startTime": "3.100s",
                            "word": "read"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "4.300s",
                            "startTime": "3.300s",
                            "word": "you"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "4.400s",
                            "startTime": "4.300s",
                            "word": "the"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "6s",
                            "startTime": "4.400s",
                            "word": "opening"
                        },
                        {
                            "endTime": "6.200s",
                            "startTime": "6s",
                            "word": "question."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "languageCode": "en-US"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

You can use this Python script to parse the JSON and save the output to a text file:

```
import json

with open('your-json-file.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

results = data['results']

output = ''

for resultIndex, result in enumerate(results):
    sentence = result['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
    startOffset = result['alternatives'][0]['words'][0]['startOffset']
    output += f"{startOffset}\t{sentence}\n"

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(output)

print('Output has been written to output.txt')
```

Or you can use this Python script if you want to transform the JSON file to a JSON file containing only the sentences:

```
import json

with open('your-json-file.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

results = data['results']

sentences = []

for result in results:
    transcript = result['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
    sentences.append(transcript)

output_data = json.dumps(sentences, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(output_data)

print('Output has been written to output.json')
```